# C++, how to delete member **object (using delete)

Tags: c++, pointers, object, member, delete-operator

I have an `**object` (`**personnel`) as a member inside(composition) another object, I want to free the memory that `**personnel` points to and point it to another `**temp` (`personnel=temp`), without `delete`ing `**personnel` and just doing `personnel=temp` the program runs well, but if I am trying to `delete **personnel` it messes everything up and I always get an error "`_Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse)`"

(I have destructors(and `virtual` base destructor) , some of them do nothing but I still get the error).     (I've tried `delete personnel[i]`, `delete []personnel[i]` and etc from all angles))

(lost few days on this)

Am I doing something wrong, is it even right to `delete` it, and if so, how do I do it?

edit:

```
if(personnel!=NULL)
    {
        for(i=0;i<numberofemployees;i++)
        { **/*what to do here*/**

    delete []this->personnel[i];

        }
        /*delete personnel;*/

    }
    personnel=temp;
    numberofemployees++;

    }
```

**personnel is a member in this class,
 (Employee **personnel,  employee is a base class of other derived classes, 
all kinds of employees, I am using polymorphism ),
 this function is just to add an employee,
 the function is long that's why I put only part of it,
 I hope you understand me, 
if I don't delete is seems everything works good, else I get assertion error,

Comment: Delete works with addresses. So if you want to delete something, pass it an address. `ptr **` is an address to a location of memory that stores another address. Which one do you want to delete?

Comment: Can you give a code sample?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question.  But, based on my understanding, if you have:

```
struct Foo { ... };
Foo* foo = new Foo;
Foo** bar = &foo;
```

Then you only need to `delete foo` or `delete *bar` (call **only one** of those).

But you generally don't want to keep track of stuff like that, and should instead consider using smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.